# El emulador de Android deja de funcionar cada vez que reinicio mi equipo, error dev/kvm permission denied

Tags: android-studio, linux, ubuntu, seguridad

Cada vez que reinicio mi equipo el emulador de Android deja de funcionar.

El error que muestra es el siguiente: ***`dev/kvm permission denied`***

Logro resolverlo ejecutando este comando en la Terminal:

```
sudo chown miUsuario /dev/kvm
```

A partir de ahí el emulador se inicia de nuevo pudiendo testear mis aplicaciones. Pero cuando reinicio el equipo tengo de nuevo que ejecutar:

```
sudo chown miUsuario /dev/kvm
```

¿Hay alguna forma de otorgar este permiso permanentemente y sin riesgo para no tener que otorgarlo cada vez cuando reinicio el equipo?

Comment: ¿No deberías usar la opción `-R` para cambiar el owner de TODOS los archivos?

Comment: @Marcos ¿a qué te refieres con cambiar el owner de todos los archivos? ¿afecta esto a la seguridad de algún modo? No tengo experiencia en Linux. Aclaro que no es un servidor ni nada, es mi equipo personal y `miUsuario` es mi usuario único para todo.

Comment: La opción `-R` indica que el cambio sea recursivo, es decir, aplica el cambio de owner a todos los archivo incluyendo los que están en sub-directorios. Si ejecutas el comando sin indicar esto, solo se afecta a los archivos en el directorio indicado (_excluyendo los que se encuentran en sub-directorios dentro del directorio_)